# How to add action buttons to ionic push notifications?

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework

I want to add some action buttons to ionic push notification. I'm using cordova pushv5. The notifications works fine but I don't know how to add these buttons.

**How do I add these buttons?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Action Buttons should be added at the POST request.

```
{
"registration_ids": ["my device id"],
"data": {
    "title": "AUX Scrum",
    "message": "Scrum: Daily touchbase @ 10am Please be on time so we can cover everything on the agenda.",
    "actions": [
        { "icon": "emailGuests", "title": "EMAIL GUESTS", "callback": "app.emailGuests", "foreground": true},
        { "icon": "snooze", "title": "SNOOZE", "callback": "app.snooze", "foreground": false}
    ]
   }
}
```

[image]

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons

Comment: I've tried...still not working...
Here is my json:
{
 "tokens":["token"],
 "profile":"crewapp",
 "notification":{
  "message":"Aloha",
  "actions": [
        { "icon": "emailGuests", "title": "EMAIL GUESTS", "callback": "app.emailGuests", "foreground": true},
        { "icon": "snooze", "title": "SNOOZE", "callback": "app.snooze", "foreground": false}
    ]
 }
 
}
I'm using cordovaV5 push plugin.Should be a reason?

Comment: what means 'not working'? is the notification recived? maybe the buttons are not diplayed? displayed but the callback fails?

Comment: Notification is received succesfully.But no any  buttons are added to notification

Comment: I found the solution.I'm sending the notification using ionic api.I've tried with fcm-node module and is working :)

Comment: Does anyone try this solution on iOS?

Comment: can u pls guide me how you achieve?

Comment: action button don't displayed:
Here is my Code
 notification: {
             title: 'Title of your push notification', 
             body: 'Body of your push notification' ,
            actions: [

        { icon: "emailGuests", title: "EMAIL GUESTS", callback: "emailGuests", foreground: false},
        { icon: "snooze", title: "SNOOZE", callback: "snooze", foreground: false},

    ]

Comment: @ggigle How exactly do you try? Can you post some code as an answer in this question? I am using FCM-node and it is still not showing.

Answer (score 1):

In PushV5's notificationReceived event, you could pop up the notification with Ionic's Alert Component, which has customizable buttons.

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data){
   let alert = alertCtrl.create({
      title: data.title,
      message: data.message,
      buttons: [
      {
          text: 'Nope',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Nope clicked');
          }
      },
      {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('OK clicked');
          }
      }
    ]
   });

   //popup the alert
   alert.present();
});
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert

Comment: This is a solution if i have my app running in background or if it's opened.If my app is stopped the notification will come without any button.I've found something about an actions array that should be added in the notification json.But still not working...